# Maria DB Unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, mariadb

I've been struggling with this error. I'm running Ubuntu **16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)**.

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0
Suggested packages:
  mailx mariadb-test tinyca
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,717 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.0:
 mariadb-client-10.0 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-client-core-10.0 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-core-10.0
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-10.0:
 mariadb-client-core-10.0 conflicts with mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.0 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.29+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (= 10.0.29+maria-1~xenial) but 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.29+maria-1~xenial) but 10.0.29+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
 mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.29+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by manual installation of MariaDB as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial main'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mariadb-common libmysqlclient18 libmariadbclient18
mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
mariadb-server-10.0 libmariadbclient-dev mariadb-server
```

After that set the same  root password you had before.

Comment: That's not a manual installation. That's using a PPA to install a different version. To be complete, I suggest adding that  PPAs are not supported software - it the PPA software gives you trouble, we can't help you much.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial main'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client mariadb-server

That will install mariaDb 10.1 using the ppa you just selected. What you did,
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mariadb-common libmysqlclient18 libmariadbclient18
mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
mariadb-server-10.0 libmariadbclient-dev mariadb-server
```

Installs mariaDb-10.0 using the ripo that ships with OS. I think that is not a very good idea.

Your error was because the OS ships with mariaDB 10.0 and 5.5 and your installation specified both.